# How to know what type of optical media is in the drive using .net

Tags: .net

After taking a look at the information available in the WMI I discovered that there was no difference in the listed properties between having a CD R disk inserted or a DVD R inserted so WMI doesn't seem to know this information.

However, in Windows 7 with auto-play turned on it always pops a dialog that knows the media type and even if it is a blank disk. Also Windows explorer knows the difference. Anybody know how to access this information through system calls or directly in .Net (2.0, 3.0, 3.5, or 4.0)

Comment: Can you check the _size_ of the inserted media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to access IMAPI v2,  for which there is no offical .net warpper.

Heres a link to IMAPI doc.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/KB932716

Having said that, i've used this before

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/net/code/libraries/writing_cds/imapi/article.asp

You'll need the DiscRecorder functiom, and you can download a sample app using this wrapper from the left hand sidebar.

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks.  From this I got to the Python library https://pypi.org/project/pyIMAPI/ which sis looking promising.